# Make a div bigger than wrapper

Tags: html

Is it possible to have a wrapper that have a width of `1000px;` but on the same time i want a DIV inside that DIV, to be `100%` width

Is that possible by any chance.

My code is something like this

```
<div class="block1">
    <img src="images/page1-img2.jpg" alt="" class="img-radius">
    <div class="border-1">
        <p class="color-1">Security Systems for Office</p>
        <p>Facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button top-1">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Around this i want another div, that is `width:100%` even that my wrapper is only `1000px`;

Comment: _100%_ of what? To `document` or the parent `div`?

Comment: 100% of the screen size :) i can try upload the page, so you can see it, then its easier to explain, what i 100% wnant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible - assuming no parent elements are positioned non-statically - but you'll have to position the inner div absolutely:

```css
#inner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    
    background: blue;
}
#wrap {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    
    margin-left: 50px;
    
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"><div id="inner"></div></div>
```

It's worth noting that I would generally try and avoid situations like this unless you really have to because it's kinda counter-intuitive.

Comment: assuming no parents are positioned relatively

Comment: But, if i do that. It will only be 100% from where the wrapper starts, to the end of right side :)

I want it to go all the way from LEFT side to RIGHT side.
On the same time, i want the WRAPPER which is 1000px; with margin:0 auto (to center it)

Comment: How can i be sure the wrapper always will be 100% centered then :) ?